# Bulk Insert csv file into SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to use bulk insert to insert values from csv file into SQL.  Here is what the csv file looks like:

```
Fruit   Quantity    Cost
Apple   2           $2 
Banana  1           $0.50 
Orange  9           $6
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
Create Table MyFruit 
    (
        Fruit varchar(50),
        Qty Int,
        Cost Float
    )


BULK INSERT MyFruit
FROM '\\APPFS\user_home$\username\Temp\Fruit.csv'
WITH(
FIRSTROW = 1,
--FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

Select * From MyFruit
```

I keep getting the below errors:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

I am using SQLServer2012

Comment: That's a hidden share, user share too, the SQL Server account might not have permissions to that share. Move the file to a local drive on the server if you can.

Comment: Thanks,  I will need to check with IT to see if they can do that to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: use fieldterminator = \t for example. FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a security setting with the server.